# Facebook for Android app no longer displays og:image of website served via home computer's IP

Tags: facebook, images, cache

I've followed the advice given in [this post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73056/facebook-sharer-php-not-updating-shared-information-after-page-update). I have updated the Facebook cache, and shared a website on Facebook on my Facebook timeline (shared only with me for testing purposes) via a web browser. When I do this, the image in the sharer looks fine, and when I go to my Facebook page I can see the shared link details as well as its corresponding image, which is a 1200x630 PNG (the text is displayed immediately but the image takes about 6 seconds to load, despite the fact that I thought such image would have been stored in the FB cache).

The story is different on my **Facebook for Android app**. I had previously shared a website whose site image is a 1200x630 PNG, and I can still see that image on my FB Timeline despite the fact that it's been removed from my site a few days ago and replaced with another image. The problem is that the newer og:image I've updated on my website, which is the same size and format as the older one it replaces, displays fine on my mobile phone's web browser and on my PC's web browser, but does not show up in my Facebook app for Android, and a blank ligh-gray rectangule with the shared og:title and my home computer's IP but **no og:image shows up in the shared post**. A whole day has gone past since I've updated the FB cache, and I've tried the Facebook Debugger Tool once again, but the image just won't show.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Questions about Android apps should be asked at [android.se].

Comment: OK, sorry, please migrate my question (which I have already answered). Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct migration path, so a Moderator will have to do the migration. I have submitted a flag to that effect.

Comment: I thought being able to migrate a question was just a matter of having enough points, and looking at your profile I thought you would have had enough. Is it not so?

Comment: Only for pre-defined migration paths. This site only has pre-defined paths to [su], [webmasters.se], and [so]. Even then others with appropriate privs would need to vote to migrate. Only Moderators can migrate to any site in the network.

Comment: I don't see anthing about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) (it says 10000 points gives you access to Moderator tools). So, are the Moderators you mention SE employees?

Comment: We have moved beyond the purpose of comments. If you have a question about how the site works you should ask on Meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried installing the Facebook app on an a friend's Android phone and the images display fine there, despite the Android app on my phone, which is even faster, still doesn't display the image. This means the problem is a caching problem (e.g. I previously shared from my site while it had a bug, and the cached information is not being updated).

So, since I couldn't find a place where I could delete the Facebook for Android app's cache, I deleted the Facebook for Android application and all its data, and reinstalled it.

That fixed the problem.